# Strange issue with abs(complex) in Visual Studio C++ 2015 Update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

After updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (from Visual Studio 2015), this code no longer compiles:

```
#include<cmath>
#include<complex>
int main()
{
    std::complex<double> update(0.0, 0.0);
    double x = std::abs(update);
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting the following error when running the compiler:

```
c:\projects\foo\win64>cl /EHsc /fp:strict foo.cc

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24213.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

foo.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xcomplex(232): er
ror C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xcomplex(232): no
te: failure was caused by an undefined arithmetic operation
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xcomplex(253): no
te: see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty std::_Fabs<double>(con
st std::complex<double> &,int *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
foo.cc(6): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty std::abs<
double>(const std::complex<double> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
```

This issue seems to be tied with my usage of fp:strict, which is necessary for proper IEEE floating point.  Is this an issue with my code?

Comment: "necessary for proper IEEE floating point" is somewhat overstating it.

Comment: @Alan Stokes not really (IMHO). If you *depend* on the specified behaviour of IEEE-754, then you *need* `/fp:strict` with Microsoft's compiler (well, it's the default, but you still need what it implements - the other options don't implement 754 to the letter)...

Comment: Could be https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2703036

Comment: confirmed, looks like a compiler bug - cannot get constexpr with division

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks for finding this.  This is a real drag since appveyor has moved to this compiler.

Comment: Maybe include it in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test it in VS2013 with update 5 and VS2015 with update 3, it really has this issue in VS2015, but everything compiled normally in VS2013 with the same property settings /fp:strict. I help you submit a new feedback to the connect report here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3101450/c2131-expression-did-not-evaluate-to-a-constant-error-in-vs2015-update-3

Maybe the report team could provide better solution for this issue. You could vote it.

Comment: Thank you for submitting the report.

Comment: You are welcome, you could view the connect report, if there are any updates from the report teams, they will update the comments there. I will also help you follow up it.

Comment: Page not found after opening the report.